# Error "Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build my first Flutter project that was given to me by my mentor. I did not change any code in my project, but I encountered this problem.

> Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'. 
> FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);

How can I solve this? I already tried most known solutions, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using some Firebase dependency that is upgrading the Firebase Core Platform to the version 4.5.2. So you should explicitly add the version 4.5.1 in the dependencies of your *pubspec.yaml* file like this:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

Comment: That works... Thank you. To be honest I made a mistake trying to do that before. There is **firebase_core_platform_interface:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: firebase_core_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.5.2"** in **pubspec.lock** folder. I was trying to change this part. So I couldn't make it. I think I was overthinking :) Thanks a lot anyway.